# How to update state itself using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm stuck trying to update the state of a simple cart but can't get it to work. Basically when I click to update state, it seems not getting the initial state, only on the second round. So how to make it work correctly?

```
const { product } = props;
const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState(0);
const [itemQty, setItemQty] = useState(0);

const handleCart = (event) => {
    const id = product.itemId;
    const price = product.price;
    setSubTotal(subTotal + Number(price));
    setItemQty(itemQty + 1);
}

return (
    <div>
        <Image
            src={product.url}
            alt={product.title}
            className="product__image"
        />
        <div className="product__title">{product.title}</div>
        <div className="product__price">{`$ ${product.price}`}</div>
        <Button
            className="product__qty-btn-p btn btn-primary"
            type="button"
            data-id="increase"
            onClick={() => handleCart()}
            id="basic-addon2"
        >
        Add
        </Button>
    </div>
)
```

Comment: What is the context? Which state does not update? I dont see any usage of any of the `subTotal`, `itemQty` states in this code. I think you meant to show `subTotal` instead of `produce.price`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happen because state is asynchronous.

You can use `useEffect` to `console.log` that state:

```
import React.{useState,useEffect} from "react"
const { product } = props;
const [subTotal, setSubTotal] = useState(0);
const [itemQty, setItemQty] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => console.log(subTotal,itemQty),[subTotal,itemQty])

const handleCart = (event) => {
    const id = event.product.itemId;
    const price = event.product.price;
    setSubTotal(prev => {prev + Number(price)});
    setItemQty(prev => {prev + 1});
}
```